# flutter: convert splash screen from image to video

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have the following splash screen and I want to insert an animated video instead of the logo image.

I tried to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySaVFCpK4M8&t=102s
and it made me change the whole code but I ended up stuck with a black screen.

so i need to modify the code below to view the video instead of the image.

any help will be appreciated thank you.

```
import 'package:cirilla/constants/assets.dart';
import 'package:cirilla/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ui/painter/zoom_painter.dart';

import 'widgets/zoom_animation.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key, this.color, this.loading}) : super(key: key);

  final Color? color;
  final bool? loading;

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Size size = Size.zero;
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late ZoomAnimation _animation;
  AnimationStatus _status = AnimationStatus.forward;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
      vsync: this,
    )
      ..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
        setState(() {
          _status = status;
        });
      })
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    _animation = ZoomAnimation(_controller);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    setState(() {
      size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    });
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant SplashScreen oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (!widget.loading! && _controller.status != AnimationStatus.forward) {
      _controller.forward();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_status == AnimationStatus.completed) return Container();

    return Stack(children: [
      SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: ZoomPainter(color: widget.color!, zoomSize: _animation.zoomSize.value * size.width),
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: itemPaddingExtraLarge),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: _animation.textOpacity.value,
            child: Image.asset(Assets.logo, width: 200, height: 200, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: The splash screen provided by the operating system is before your app is running, and has some pretty heavy limitations, such as being only a static image.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz any way to change that?

Comment: Rewrite your own Android and ios, and make it popular. :)